# How to log out using PKCE authorization flow?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, okta

If I have an `app` and an `api`. If the `app` logs in through authorization server and sends the `authorization: Bearer xxx` header with each request, the `api` can verify the token locally.
When the user logs out (through the auth server), but the `token` has not yet expired if someone retrieves this `token` they will be able to make requests (if the authentication of the token is done locally on the server), is that correct? If thats the case, why is such a logout flow considered secure?

Edit: Clarifying the main question: why PKCE flow is considered secure if when a user logs out their access token is still valid (given we do local token verification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BEHAVIOUR OVERVIEW**

With OAuth there is a greater separation of concerns than in older standalone web apps:

- You log into UIs
- This is externalised to an Authorization Server
- An access token is issued with a fixed / short lifetime
- Access tokens are used as API message credentials
- The access token can potentially be sent to other components and used from there

When you logout:

- You remove tokens from your app
- You redirect to tell the Authorization Server the user is no longer logged into any UI
- This doesn't invalidate access tokens

**TOKEN STORAGE**

Tokens should be stored in private memory or protected storage so that attackers cannot access them easily. Your app then removes tokens as part of the logout process so that they are no longer available for attackers to try to access.

**THREATS**

The [OAuth Threat Model](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-4.1.3) has a section on stolen tokens, where it recommends the above storage and to keep tokens short lived. The most common industry default for an access token is 60 minutes.

The main risk of a malicious party stealing a token is via cross site scripting. XSS risks are not related to logout. Security testing should be performed regularly to ensure that XSS risks are mitigated.

**BALANCE BETWEEN SECURITY AND PERFORMANCE**

It may be possible for the UI to tell the Authorization Server that a token is revoked. However, the API would then need to call the Authorization Server on every API request to check for token revocation. This would lead to poor performance.

**API ARCHITECTURE**

I always aim to use [Claims Caching](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/) and introspection in OAuth secured APIs, since it gives the actual API best control, along with good extensibility and performance.

With this in place, if you really wanted to make access tokens non usable after logout, without ruining performance, your UI could perform these actions as part of the logout process:

- Revoke the access token at the Authorization Server (if supported)
- Call APIs to ask them to remove cached claims for the access token

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but isn't the whole point of log out is to make sure that whatever credentials you were using to make requests are no longer valid? This is what trips me over. Stateless JWT seem (at least to me) insecure. When would you opt in vs opt out of using such authorization flow?

Comment: So what concrete / real world problems do you think will occur? Sometimes it is not worth getting tied up in technicalities like this - when the user logs out your app should just remove tokens at the same time. This is how most OAuth UIs work, and they are not considered insecure.

Comment: I'm thinking of a hypothetical scenario where an attacker obtains your `access_token` after you have logged out, but the token has not yet expired. They will be able to use it freely until expiration if the API server is doing local token verification.

Comment: Have a look at the [OAuth Threat Model](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6819#section-4.1.3) section on dealing with the threat of stolen tokens. In a nutshell they recommend storing tokens in private memory / protected storage and keeping them short lived.

Comment: Thanks for this. I understand that by design it's hard to steal the tokens and there are mitigations for when that happens. What I still fail to comprehend (maybe me being thick skulled) is the logout. Is it the case that the likelihood of the token being stolen is so small that such a scenario can be ignored?

Comment: I marked this as an accepted answer, but would be great if you could update the answer with some of the points you made in the comments above.

Comment: Ok - have done - thanks for the interesting discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Okta /introspect can tell you if active is true or false, you could check that on every request if you are not slamming the API https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/#introspect

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to get access to the token, that's probably a good reason why it's not per definition insecure.

However, providing a logout option is a good idea. OAuth2 has a 'revoke' feature to make sure that tokens are revoked:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009

Not every server supports this.