# How to group user's access_token by session?

Tags: oauth-2.0

There are oauth2 server and some services.

[image]

Some user has authorized on computer in 2 services and get 2 access_tokens. And this user has authorized on mobile in some service and get another access_token.

User logout on computer from all services. Logout must invalidate all access_token from this session (computer): tokens 123, 789.

How correct bind access_token and user session?
OAuth2 server has web frontend and remember user by JWT token in cookie. Is it normal bind access_token with this JWT token, and where user click Logout in oAuth2 server, than get all access_token, tied with such JWT token and invalidate them?

Answer (score 1):

The general mechanism works like this:

- Access tokens are short lived ~ 60 minutes
- They are issued to 'clients' - usually UIs / apps
- When you log out of a client you remove its access tokens
- This does not remove tokens from other clients on the same computer
- But the access tokens used by the other clients will expire soon and the user will need to login again

See also my [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62584885/how-to-log-out-using-pkce-authorization-flow/62596015#62596015) and the performance impact of services needing to check access token validity on every single request.

It is worth thinking about what the real concern / requirement is here. Sometimes opinions are based on how older / standalone solutions worked, but there can be a large cost to trying to implement the same thing in an OAuth architecture.

Comment: Yes, I need to remove access_tokens from services (clients) upon logout by perfomance reason. Any service don't check access_token on each request in their system, so question is appeared how to realize logout for this scheme. Obvious solution is simple remove access tokens from all services by special logout link by each service.

I check your link about Claims Caching, I hope it give some answer.

Comment: As I understand text on that link, there is proposal to cache requests for check access_token (for example for 10 seconds or 1 minute). This is not good for my case, because by logout all services must make logout.

Related to phrase "there can be a large cost to trying to implement the same thing in an OAuth architecture.". I don't want to realize this, but I can't see alternative solution, where these requirements is implemented.

Comment: No problem - hope my write ups give you some ideas. It can be very tricky to get APIs to reject access tokens immediately after logout, while ensuring good performance and clean separation. Most people don't worry about doing this and just remove tokens from the app at the time of logout.